# How to list the jComboBox values

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I m using  jComboBox to display the date,month,year and i add the first item in jComboBox as  DD,MM,YY(i set the first item as "DD,YY" in model properties of jComboBox).To display the date and year value i used for loop.The code follows..

```html
    //for date
    private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    for(int k=1;k<=31;k++)
    {

        jComboBox1.addItem(k);
    }
} 

    //for year
    private void jComboBox3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    for(int n=1980;n<=2012;n++)
    {

        jComboBox3.addItem(n);
    }
}
```

So my problem is when i select the DD and YY jComboBox it didn't display the values dynamically.For example when i click the DD jComboBox  in the list it shows another item as DD and then if i select only means it display the all values for DD and YY. why?? and how display it dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

- no idea, bo better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about `JFrame` (layed by `FlowLayout` or `GridLayout`) and three `JComboBoxes`
- see [`JComboBox.getSelectedItem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedItem%28%29) or add [ItemListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html) to `JComboBox`
- I'd be use [JSpinner with SpinnerListModel/SpinnerDateModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) instead of [JComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)

Comment: I'm uisng NetBeans.I want to know how to add DATE,MONTH,YEAR in jComboBox via loop and i want the first item in the list as DD,MM,YY.How to do tat??

Answer (score 1):

your code initialize the JComboBox each time the user click on it , this is wrong

```
private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

////////////here you put the action like getSelectedItem() which return the item 

}
```

Comment: I,m using **netbeans IDE**i want the first item in jComboBox as DD for date,MM for Month and YY for YEAR and then i used for loop to add respective  values..And also i tried as                                                                                                                     private void jComboBox3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)  {                                           
jComboBox.setSelectedItem("DD");
for(int n=1980;n<=2012;n++)
{ jComboBox3.addItem(n);}          
it wouldn't add DD as first item in jComboBox if i use for loop..How to do tat????

Answer (score 1):

Check this code

```
public class ComboBoxDatePicker extends JPanel implements ItemListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JComboBox myDay;
    private JComboBox myMonth;
    private JComboBox myYear;
    private Collection<ItemListener> myListeners;

    public ComboBoxDatePicker(String name) {
        this(name, new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }

    public ComboBoxDatePicker(String name, Date date) {
        super(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        myListeners = new HashSet<ItemListener>();

        myDay = new JComboBox(new RangeModel(1, 31));
        myMonth = new JComboBox(new RangeModel(1, 12));
        myYear = new JComboBox(new RangeModel(2000, 2020));

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        myDay.setSelectedItem(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        myMonth.setSelectedItem(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
        myYear.setSelectedItem(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));

        myDay.addItemListener(this);
        myMonth.addItemListener(this);
        myYear.addItemListener(this);

        add(new JLabel(name));
        add(myDay);        
        add(myMonth);
        add(myYear);

        doLayout();
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        myDay.setEnabled(enabled);
        myMonth.setEnabled(enabled);
        myYear.setEnabled(enabled);
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        if (!myDay.isEnabled()) {
            return null;
        }

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.clear();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, (Integer) myDay.getSelectedItem());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, (Integer) myMonth.getSelectedItem() - 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, (Integer) myYear.getSelectedItem());
        return calendar.getTime();
    }

    private static class RangeModel implements ComboBoxModel {

        private int myMin;
        private int myMax;
        private Object mySelection;

        public RangeModel(int min, int max) {
            myMin = Math.min(min, max);
            myMax = Math.max(min, max);
            mySelection = myMin;
        }
        public Object getSelectedItem() {
            return mySelection;
        }
        public void setSelectedItem(Object anItem) {
            mySelection = anItem;
        }
        public int getSize() {
            return myMax - myMin + 1;
        }
        public Object getElementAt(int index) {
            return myMin + index;
        }
        public void addListDataListener(ListDataListener l) {
        }
        public void removeListDataListener(ListDataListener l) {
        }
    }

    public void addItemListener(ItemListener l) {
        myListeners.add(l);
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        for (ItemListener listener : myListeners) {
            listener.itemStateChanged(e);
        }
    }
}
```

and you can use this where ever you need

```
  JFrame frame = new JFrame() ;
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  ComboBoxDatePicker chooser = new ComboBoxDatePicker("Choose Date");
  frame.add(chooser);
  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a jframe then you can write code to dynamically add values to the combo box in the `WindowActivated` event of the jframe like this:

```
private void formWindowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
// TODO add your handling code here:
    //for Day
    for(int i=1;i<=31;i++)
    {
        jComboBox1.addItem(i);
    }
    //for Month
    for(int i=1;i<=12;i++)
    {
        jComboBox2.addItem(i);
    }
}
```